# Perl input multiple text files from command line and print them

Tags: perl

I'm trying to find the number of positive (P) and negative integers (N), number of words with all lower case characters(L),all upper case characters(F), Number  of  words  with  the  first character capital  and  the  rest  of  characters  lower  case(U).
List  of  words  in  alphabetical  order  together  with  the  line  number  and  the filename  of  each  occurrence The  following  example  illustrates the  output  of  the  program  on  sample  input.

#### file1

```
Hello!  world  my  friend.  ALI  went  to  school.  Ali  has  -1 dollars and 10 TL
```

#### file2

```
Hello  there  my  friend.  VELI  went  to  school.  Veli  has  10,  
dollars  and  -10,TL
```

After    you  run  your  program,

```
>prog.pl file1 file2
```

the  output  you  get  is  as  follows:

```
N=2
P=2
L=18
F=4
U=4

-----------
ali file1 (1 1)
and file1 (2) file2 (2)
dollars file1 (2) file2 (2)
friend file1 (1) file2 (1)
has file1 (1) file2 (1)
hello file1 (1) file2 (1)
my file1 (1) file2 (1)
school file1 (1) file2 (1)
there file2 (1)
tl file1 (2) file2 (2)
to file1 (1) file2 (1)
veli file2 (1 1)
went file1 (1) file2 (1)
world file1 (1)
```

I tried to fill the entries,could you help me to deal with it?

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
$N= 0 ;
$P= 0 ;
$L= 0 ;
$F= 0 ;
$U= 0 ;
foreach __________ ( ____________) {__________________
        or die("Cannot opened because: $!") ;
    $lineno = 0 ;
    while($line=<>) {
        chomp ;
        $lineno++ ;
        @tokens = split $line=~ (/[ ,.:;!\?]+/) ;
        foreach $str (@tokens) {
            $N++ if ($str =~ /^-\d+$/) ;
            $P++ if ($str =~ /^\d+$/) ;
            $L++ if ($str =~ /^[a-z]+$/) ;
            $F++ if ($str =~ /^[A-Z][a-z]+$/) ;
            $U++ if ($str =~ /^[A-Z]+$/) ;
            if ($str =~ /^[a-zA-Z]+$/) {
                $str =~ __________________;
                if ( (____________________) || ($words{$str} =~ /\)$/ ) ) {
                    $words{$str} = $words{$str} . " " . $file . " (" . $lineno ;
                }
                else {_______________________________________;
                }}}}
    close(FH) ;
    foreach $w (__________________) {
        if ( ! ($words{$w} =~ /\)$/ )) {
            $words{$w} = ______________________;
        }}}
print "N=$N\n" ;
print "P=$P\n" ;
print "L=$L\n" ;
print "F=$F\n" ;
print "U=$U\n" ;
print "-----------\n" ;
foreach $w (sort(keys(%words))) {
    print $w," ", $words{$w}, "\n";
}
```

Comment: Aside, denoting "N" to represent positive numbers and "P" to represent negative numbers is confusing. See your first sentence. I'm hoping that was just a typo though :). Please correct if so.

Comment: This looks like obvious homework. Please provide your attempts

Comment: Is this an end-of-the-semester assignment/quiz/exam?

Comment: YeS.This is an assignment.I filled some blanks but not all..

Comment: You need to learn how to use [Markdown](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Markdown) to format your questions. I've reformatted your question, so the program is easier to read (including correct indentations) and making the rest of it a bit easier to see.

Comment: Who is teaching you Perl? I really am interested because this is based upon Perl syntax from 30 years ago when Perl was merely a substitute for shell and awk. Whoever is teaching this course is teaching you a programming style that is completely out of date with how Perl is programmed today.

Answer (score 2):

A few hints, and I'll let you get on your way...

Perl has what is called a *diamond operator*. This operator opens all files placed on the command line (which is read into the `@ARGS` array), and reads them line-by-line.

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use autodie;
use feature qw(say);

while my $line ( <> ) {
    chomp $line;
    say "The line read in is '$line'";
}
```

Try this program and run it as you would your program. See what happens.

Next, take a look at the Perl documentation for [variables related to file handles](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html#Variables-related-to-filehandles). Especially take a look at the `$/` variable. This variable is what used to break *records*. It's normally set to a new-line, so when you read in a file, you read it in line-by-line. You may want to try that. If not, you can fall back onto something like this:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use autodie;
use feature qw(say);

while my $line ( <> ) {
    chomp $line;
    @words = split /\s+/, $line;
    for my $word ( @words ) {
        say "The word is '$word'";
    }
}
```

Now you can use a hash to track which words were in each file and how many times. You can also track the various types of words you've mentioned. However, please don't use variables such as `$U`. Use `$first_letter_uppercase`. This will have more meaning in your program and will be less confusing for you.

Your teacher is teaching you the way Perl was written almost 30 years ago. This was back before God created the Internet. (Well, not quite. The Internet was already 10 years old, but no one outside of a few academics had heard of it). Perl programming has greatly evolved since then. Get yourself a good book on *Modern* Perl (that is Perl 5.x).

The *pragmas* at the beginning of my program (the *use* statements) do the following:

- `use strict` - Use *strict* syntax. This does several things, but the main thing is to make sure you cannot use a variable unless you first *declare* it. (using most likely `my`). This prevents mistakes such as putting `$name` in one place, and referring to `$Name` in another place.
- `use warnings` - This warns you of basic errors such as you're attempting to *use* a variable that isn't defined. By default, Perl assumes the variable is a null string or equal to zero if you use it in an arithmetic context. When you attempt to print or check a variable that hasn't been assigned a value. It probably means you have a logic mistake.

The above two *pragmas* will catch 90% of your errors.

- `use autodie` - This will cause your program to automatically die in many circumstances. For example, you attempt to open a none existent file for reading. This way, you don't have to remember to check each instance of whether or not certain operations succeeded of failed.
- `use feature qw(say)` - This allows you to use `say` instead of `print`. The `say` command is just like `print`, but automatically adds a new line on the end. It can make your code way cleaner and easier to understand.

For example:

```
print "N=$N\n" ;
```

vs.

```
say "N=$N" ;
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I'd write that program. But it won't get you many marks as it's a long way from the "fill in the blanks" approach that your teacher is using. But that's good, because your teacher's Perl is very dated.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use 5.010;

my ($N, $P, $L, $F, $U);
my %words;

while (<>) {
  my @tokens = split /[^-\w]+/;
  foreach my $token (@tokens) {
    $N++ if $token =~ /^-\d+$/;
    $P++ if $token =~ /^\d+$/;
    next unless $token =~ /[a-z]/i;
    $L++ if $token eq lc $token;
    $U++ if $token eq uc $token;
    $F++ if $token eq ucfirst lc $token;
    push @{$words{lc $token}{$ARGV}}, $.;
  }
  close ARGV if eof;
}

say "N=$N";
say "P=$P";
say "L=$L";
say "F=$F";
say "U=$U";

for my $word (sort { $a cmp $b } keys %words) {
  print "$word ";
  for my $file (sort { $a cmp $b } keys %{$words{$word}} ) {
    print "$file (", join(' ', @{$words{$word}{$file}}), ') ';
  }
  print "\n";
}
```